# How do I convert a MySQL database view to Rails using Active Record Query Interface

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app with a model to a MySQL database view.  It works fine, but when going through migrations to AWS and Heroku, I'm realizing having database structures like views outside of Rails is not a good thing since Rails can't create views ( as far I know ) as part of the migration process, which I want to start leveraging.

Anyway, I don't understand how to replicate the view in Rails using the Active Record Query Interface.

For my example, the view joins a historys table and an items table, where the item id is a foreign key in the history table.

So my Rails app has a model for items, and historys, and am looking for a way to create a query that joins the table, much like a database view does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create views in your migrations quite easily. See more here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

```
def up
    execute 'create view my_view as select .... '
end
def down
    execute 'drop view my_view'
end
```

You can also replicate views by creating a model class inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base and set the table_name

```
class MyView < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'my_view'
end
```

You can also just use the ActiveRecord query interface to replicate what your view is doing by doing something like...

```
items = User.joins(:history).all.order(:some_column)
```

See more here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Thanks Iceman.  And if I want attributes/columns from history as well as items, I would need to add the following into the join, right?   select("items.*, historys.*")    Without this, it appears to only return the items attributes.

Comment: You can also look into the find_by_sql method if you need something special. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class